# Blue screen while installing windows XP

Tags: windows

I have a Lenovo i3 processor, 500GB HDD & 2GB RAM & installed with windows 7 OS...when I install with windows XP, at time of installing I am getting blue screen error.. could you please give me a solution for the same.

Comment: Blue screens are almost always hardware or driver problems. As you are installing, the former seems to be the place to start. A first step would be to ensure all connections (including RAM and CPU to motherboard) connections are good.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP does not have the proper SATA driver. So you might have to disable in `BIOS SATA AHCI` to `SATA Legacy/IDE` mode.

Since you are going back in time anyway disabling AHCI would not affect you because XP is slower than Windows 7 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What was the blue screen message otherwise it could be anything we have no idea what it relates to. did it give you an error code?